# jquery custom event not working in backbone

Tags: backbone.js, jquery-events

Question is why isn't the Backbone view executing the jQuery custom event handler?
I'm trying to listen for the enter key on an text box and when the enter key is pressed, and only the enter key, I want to execute a function.  I'm using require.js 2.1.15, jquery 1.11.1, backbone 1.1.2 and underscore 1.7.

The idea is to register the "enter.js" plugin with jquery.

```
(function (factory) {
        if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
            // AMD. Register as an anonymous module depending on jQuery.
            console.log("require.js registered");
            define(['jquery'], factory);
        } else {
            // No AMD. Register plugin with global jQuery object.
            console.log("no amd registered");
            factory(jQuery);
        }
    }(function ($) {
        console.log('registered event listener for input on the enter key');
        $('input').keyup(function(e) {
            console.log("key input");
            if(e.keyCode == 13){
                console.log("enter key assessed");
                $(this).trigger('enter');
            }
        })
    }));
```

This executes and registers with no errors in the console.
`require.js registered                                       enter.js:12`
`registered event listener for input on the enter key        Problem.js:4`

Now the backbone code:

```
define(function (require) {
  "use strict";

  console.log("start of ArithmeticView.js");
  var
  $                 = require('jquery'),
  enter     = require('../../$plugins/enter'),
  _                 = require('underscore'),
  Backbone  = require('backbone'),
  tpl               = require('text!tpls/ArithmeticView.html'),
  ProblemModels         = require('../models/Problem'),

  template  = _.template(tpl);


  return Backbone.View.extend( {

    el: 'body',


    events: {
      "enter .answer": "solve",
    },
  initialize: function(){
      this.render();
      this.displayProblem();
    },
    render: function() {
      console.log("render ArithmeticView");
      return this.$el.html(template());
    },
    solve: function() {
            console.log("solving ProblemModels.Problem");
        var givenAnswer = $(".answer").val();
            if(givenAnswer == this.problem.get("answer")) {
                return this.displayProblem();
             }
            return this;   
    },
    displayProblem: function() {
        this.problem = new ProblemModels.Problem;
            $('.problemArea').text(this.problem.get("question"));
            return this;
    }    
  });
});
```

When I debug in Chrome console I can see the enter listener attached to the textarea with the class answer attached to it.  I don't see anywhere in the console the actual function code as coded in the jQuery plugin enter.

Comment: try changing `textarea` to `input`, `enter.js` registers for keyup on `input`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated:

I totally understand your specifications, in fact I personally like the way you're handling the '`enter`' event. Except that the way you're implementing it, it will never work with dynamically loading HTML (think templates).

> The reason your view isn't listening to the '`enter`' event is because it's *not there*

Yea, I know, I know. The enter.js plugin is binding to all `<input>` elements. All of them that are there at the time it's doing the binding. From the jQuery docs (emphasis theirs):

> **Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to `.on()`**

When you populate and attach template code, `_.template` returns all new DOM elements. Even bindings to all elements of a type like `$('input').on` will not protectively bind to new `<input>` elements.

### Workaround

In my opinion, your best bet is to rebind your plugin *after* you render the view.

(Normally you'd want to use delegation to get around this problem, and read the `jQuery.event.target` property in your plugin to see if the keypress came from an `<input>` element, but you can't use that in your view `events` hash because Backbone can't detect delegation.)

---

### Alternative workaround

Handle the `enter` keypress in each method that you need to listen for.

Just replace

```
"enter .answer": "solve"
```

with

```
"keypress .answer": "solve"
```

and add the following in your `solve` method

```
solve: function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    console.log("solving ProblemModels.Problem");
    var givenAnswer = $(".answer").val();
    if(givenAnswer == this.problem.get("answer")) {
      return this.displayProblem();
    }
    return this;  
  } 
}
```

Backbone will always send a jQuery `event` object to the callback of a view `event`. jQuery packages the `keyCode` property in the `event` object which saves the key detected on the `keypress` event. In your case (and if you look at your plugin) all we do is test whether the key pressed was the enter key, with a key code of 13.

The above reproduces your desired effect without the complexity of registering and then loading the plugin into scope with Require. I know it's not as neatly encapsulated as using the `enter.js` plugin but it makes the code more straightforward and it may possibly run leaner without the plugin overhead.

Comment: This solution ties event handling to the solve function whereas I wanted to leave solve to check the answer given by the user to the solution of the problem. <br> Your answer does expedite the single use case but it doesn't allow me to handle the enter event nor does it allow me to just perform the function in question. With the answer provided the function needs to know how it's fired.  Not preferred.

Comment: So working off the information that you gave me where the view wasn't listening to 'enter' event is because it's not there.  So I just moved the adding of the 'enter' listener that triggers the 'enter' event to it's own function in the view and called it from initialize right after the render function.  Works perfectly.  Thanks for your insights.